# How to clip Background Sky Texture to above Horizon

Tags: world

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to clip a Sky Texture Background to above the Horizon only, anything below it should be black.
I tried using the clip function of the mapping node but the result is something else. I also tried combining the sky texture with an rgb node with a mix shader and using the mapping node as Fac but didnt find a solution.
Please show me a working node setup.

Comment: you talking about cycles here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Generated texture coordinate with World to read Z axis on -1 to 1 range. Here -1 is straight under, 1 is straight up and 0 is the horizon. Taking it from there, you could simply use Math node to test for Greater than 0. Math node returns 0 for under 0 and 1 immeadiately above 0 so you can achieve a sharp mask.

[image: Clipped to black below 0]

For smoother options you could use Color Ramp node, it even conveniently ignores anything below 0 in the range.

EDIT: Here are couple setups for Color Ramp. First ColorRamp range from horizon to Zenith, horizon is on the left of the ColorRamp at value 0.0.

[image: ColorRamp range from Horizon to Zenith]

And here we have shifted the -1 to 1 range between 0 and 1 by adding 1 and multiplying by 0.5. Horizon is in the middle of the ColorRamp at value 0.5.

[image: ColorRamp range from Ground to Zenith]

Comment: Thank you very much, your a genius! Btw I used it for the Fac of a Mix Shader that I mixed a RGB on black with, now it works as intended.

Comment: Ok, so I added the Color Ramp between the Separate XYZ and the Color/Fac and it works, the only problem is, it doesnt go below the horizon. Gotta figure out how to achieve that. The good thing is you get the easing.

Comment: @JohnMcDon I added some ColorRamp examples.

Comment: Thanks again, I already implemented the Add and the Multiply node to move the border and control the easing. I made a node group for this but it's rather meant to be used as a factor for a mix node. If you wanna check it out: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?449053-Node-Group-Texture-Axis-Clipping-WIP&highlight=